# DB2 z/os running SQL query on a specific table partition

Tags: sql, db2

I have a db2 table that contains customer transactions.

This table is about 500 Million records and when I try to run a select query BETWEEN 
specific dates  the query runs for a long time.
A DBA in the company told me that it would run faster if i could specify the partition in my SQL.

So the question is:
Provided I have the following table whose name is Cust_Trans
With the following columns

```
Cust_Num, Trans_Date, Trans_Type, Trans_Value + 30 more columns
```

What changes can I make to the following SQL query so it will target a specific partition?

```
Select *

From Cust_Trans
```

Searching the forum and IBM documentation
I found solutions that involve SYSCAT schema and datapartitionnum function

However my DB2 version has no SYSCAT schema
but only SYSIBM schema.
So i could not implement any of the solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Db2 for Z/OS, the catalog tables are in SYSIBM schema.

For Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, the catalog views are in SYSCAT schema.

For Db2 for i-series the catalog may be in QSYS2 schema.

For Db2 for Z/OS, Look at [SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsyscolumnstable.html) for you table, the columns whose PARTKEY_COLSEQ have non-zero are the range-partitioning columns.

The suggestion is to use the partitioning column(s) in the WHERE clause of the query, presuming that at least one of the partition column(s) is the trans_date column that you mention.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed i found one partitioning field. however it is not a date field as i wished but a serial number and each partition contains about 1.5M rows.  So i created an  R script that loops over the partitions and checks what are the dates in each partition and then a second loop to send SQL to retrieve the data only in the partitions in which the desired dates were found.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know what the partitioning columns are for that table and then add a first-order predicate (WHERE  = ... or WHERE  BETWEEN ... AND ...) to your query for the "main" partitioning column ***provided*** such filtering is indeed the intent of your query.